# How do you get well-definedness in long exact sequence connecting homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $0 \to K_{\bullet}' \xrightarrow{a} K_{\bullet} \xrightarrow{b} K_{\bullet}'' \to 0$ be a short exact sequence of modules.  There exists a connecting map $c: H_{n}'' \to H_{n-1}'$ derived as follows:

Let $\bar{x} \in H_n''$ and so in particular $x \in \text{im} \ b_n$ by exactness of the complexes, so let $y \in b_n^{-1}(x)$.  But $d b_n = b_{n-1} d$ so that $dx = b_{n-1}dy = 0$.  We now need $\bar{z} \in H_{n}'$ to map to $y$. Since $dy \in \ker b_{n-1}$ by exactness of the complexes we have $dy \in \text{im} \ a_{n-1}$ so that $a_{n-1} z = dy$ for some $z \in K_{n-1}'$.

That's where I'm stuck in the mud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, so good.  Now, 
$$
a_{n-2}(dz) = d(a_{n-1}(z)) = d(dy)=0
$$
and as $a_{n-2}$ is injective we have $dz=0$.  Thus $z$ is a cycle in $K_{n-1}^{'}$ and thus represents an element in $H_{n-1}^{'}$.  Hence we may define $c: H_n^{''} \to H_{n-1}^{'}$ by $c(\bar{x}) = \bar{z}$.  Now argue that this is well-defined and a homomorphism.

Comment: Having trouble proving well definedness.  Is it best to show that it is a composition of two well-defined homs?

Comment: Right, this is the annoying part.  If you chose $y'$ instead of $y$ you would have $b(y-y') = x-x=0$ so $y-y'$ is in the kernel of $b$.  But this means $y-y' = a(w)$ for some unique $w$ by exactness.   Now $dy - dy' = d(a(w)) = ad(w)$.  At the same time, $dy-dy' = a(z)-a(z') = a(z-z')$.  Hence $dw=z-z'$ as $a$ is injective.  Thus $z$ and $z'$ define the same class.  Now handle the choice of $x$.  Keep going....

Answer (score 1):

I find it much easier to make this sort of argument using *all* preimages rather than just choosing one.

That is, in  first step of taking a preimage under $b_n$, rather than just working with the single preimage $y$, I instead take the entire class $y + a_n(K'_n)$. One can view this as an element of the quotient module $K_n / a_n(K'_n)$.

Taking the differential goes to $dy + da_n(K'_n) = dy + a_{n-1} d(K'_n)$.

Then, taking the preimage under $a_{n-1}$ gives $z + d(K'_n)$.

By doing things this way, I find it easier to see:

- that the result is *linear* in $x$
- that the chase yields a *unique* element of $K'_{n-1} / d(K'_n)$

and we thus get a well-defined homomorphism $\ker\{ K''_n \xrightarrow{d} K''_{n-1} \} \to K'_{n-1}/d(K'_n)$.